# $watch fires only on first update of window.innerWidth

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to setup my app to watch the `window.innerWidth` property and add a property to the `$scope` based on that width.  It works the first time, but not on any resize after that.  Is the $digest method not being called?  If so why not?

Module

```
//Initialize angular module include route dependencies

var app = angular.module("selfservice", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider
       .when('/', {
           templateUrl:"partials/login.html",
           controller:"login"
       });
});
```

Controller

```
app.controller("login", ['$scope', function ($scope) {


$scope.$watch(

    function () {
        return window.innerWidth;
    },

    function (newval, oldval) {
        if (newval < 700) {
            $scope.classExpand = 'expand';
        } else {
            $scope.classExpand = '';
        }

        console.log(newval, oldval);
    });



}]);
```

View

```
<div class="small-12 column">
            <a href="/portal" class="button radius large {{classExpand}}">Sign In</a>
</div>
```

This works the first time, if I refresh the screen after resizing it, the expand class is applied, but when I resize it, nothing happens, the console.log function doesn't even fire

Comment: Any reason not to bind to `window.onresize` event (which browser fires natively) instead of using a `$watch` which will only fire on Angular's schedule?

Comment: No I suppose there isn't, this is just the method I thought of first, and I'm not sure why it's not working.  Although that probably is the best way of going, I'm still curious why $watch isn't firing like it should

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resizing the window doesn't cause Angular to re-run a `$digest` loop, so `window.innerWidth`'s value is checked only when something else causes it.

You should instead use a directive (ie. don't do this work in your controller), binding to the `window.onresize` event:

```
.directive('watchResize', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      angular.element(window).on('resize', function(){
        scope.$apply(function(){
          scope.classExpand = (window.innerWidth < 700) ? 'expand' : '';
        });
      });
    }
  }
});
```

In this case, you call `scope.$apply`. This causes the $digest loop to run following this event, which is outside of the Angular context.

You can use this directive to decorate an element on the same scope as the variable you're changing:

```
<div watch-resize>
  {{ classExpand }}
</div>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/QHO0TlfBcpdnhwAgwcBx?p=preview) (best viewed full-screen)